# How to pass card information to checkout when redirecting (Stripe)

Tags: python, python-3.x, stripe-payments, checkout, credit-card

With **Python** code below, I want to pass **card information** such as **card number**, **cvc**, **name on card**, etc to **checkout** on **Stripe** when redirecting:

```py
stripe.checkout.Session.create(
    mode="payment",
    payment_method_types=['card'],
    line_items=[
        {
            'price_data': {
                'currency': 'jpy',
                'unit_amount': 2000,
                'product_data': {
                    'name': 'Honey',
                    'description': 'Good honey',
                },
            },
            "quantity": 2,
        },
    ],
    success_url="https://example.com/success",
    cancel_url="https://example.com/cancel",
)
```

[image]

I read [**Create a Session in Stripe Doc**](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create) but I couldn't find the **parameters** to do it.

So, is it impossible to pass **card information** to **checkout** on **Stripe** when redirecting?

Answer (score 1):

It’s not possible to pass along payment information to create a Checkout session. That’s essentially the point of using Stripe - your team never has to collect and store customers’ sensitive card information.

By using Checkout, your customers can securely share their payment details directly with Stripe, and these payment details never touch your server.